# Can one reduced the pressure needed to click/draw on Wacom Bamboo?

Tags: graphics-tablet, bamboo

I have a Wacom Bamboo Pad, CTH-301 and I want to start using it for drawing on a computer, but I have noticed that in order to click (or hold, for that matter), I need to apply a considerable amount of pressure (quite more than when drawing with a normal pen or pencil, for example). I was wondering whether it is possible to change that.

Ideally, I would like the tablet to detect a click-hold whenever I touch the surface of the tablet, but I am fine with just reducing the pressure necessary.

It's been like this since I've purchased it, but I have not managed to find anywhere on the web anyone mentioning a similar problem, so I didn't achieve much with Google.

I'll be thankful for any suggestions.

PS. I am not perfectly sure whether this site is the best site to post this question on, but I have seen some questions of related flavour here, so I think it should be on-topic. If not, I'd appreciate if anyone told me where this would be more suitable.

Comment: Did you go to the settings page of your device by any chance? It should be right there. Possibly listed as calibrate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where I've always adjusted that for my Wacoms:

[image: Wacom Tablet Settings panel]

Though I've not experienced a pen being difficult to click, usually the opposite.